# Pre-fill vaule when adding new row in ASPxGridView

Tags: aspxgridview

I got this ASPxGridView which is populated by  a LinqServerModeDataSource.

What I want to do is when creating a new row one (or more) of the fields should have their values generated by code-behind.

I figured something like

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues["CompanyGuid"] = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

But no luck there.
Any advices?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out

I'd have to add a reference to oninitnewrow="ASPxGridView1_InitNewRow" in the control and add the method

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInitNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues["CompanyGuid"] = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```